# How can I save a python HTTP requests from python-requets so I can execute it later?

Tags: serialization, python-requests

I want to save HTTP request made through python-requests library, so I can execute them at a later time with minimal effort.

Note, it would be great if I can save these in a format that would allow me to restore them even if the python-requests is changed.

Comment: See [Make instances of PreparedRequest class pickable](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1558)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
args = ["http://google.com"]
kwargs = {"headers": {}, "auth": None}
foo = lambda: requests.get(*args,**kwargs)
```

and later, call `foo()`

Answer (score -2):

If your intention is to save specific sites visited and explicit requests, then just write the r.url value to a text file.  Here's a basic idea:

```
import requests

url = "http://example.com/"
r = requests.get(url)

afile = open("/path/to/filename.txt", "a")
afile.write(r.url)
afile.write("\n")
afile.close()
```

Note: if you do this with a POST request and it includes authentication details, then secret data (auth keys, passwords, etc.) may be saved in the file.

Comment: Other parameters like headers, proxy, cookie, auth, etc should be serialized as well.